# Grails 1.3.7 UTF-8 issue when deployed on Tomcat6

Tags: grails, utf-8, tomcat6

I am trying to deploy an application created in 1.3.7 that recieves a notification from a desktop app and depending on the user's language, will send a language-specific 'thank you' email. The emails are created from templates using javamail MimeMessageHelper like so:

```
 MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
 helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(config.td.mail.from.email,config.td.mail.from.text))
 helper.setTo((mailDetails.to) as String)
 helper.setSubject(config.td.mail.from.regSubject)
 helper.setText(buildRegBody(mailTemplate, mailDetails), true)
```

The actual mailTemplate files are all encoded in UTF-8. When running the app locally the emails are sent out without any error but upon deployment to Tomcat any international characters in the text of the email are replaced with: �������. I have had similar problems when writing international characters to a MySQL database with correct UTF-8 collation.

My config file includes the lines:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "none"
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

I tried the following to no avail:

- Added UTF-8 encoding statements to connector elements in Tomcat server xml
- Made sure the charEncodingFilter is first in the chain in web.xml
- Created my production war using the argument: '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 war'

These seem to solve the problem for most other users and now I have run out of ideas - any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What `buildRegBody` does? Can you post the code?

Comment: Have you made sure that file.encoding is UTF-8 in the tomcat instance? If your mail templates are files encoded in UTF-8, and you use File.text to load the string interpretation, the default file enconding is used to decode the bytes of your file.

Answer (score 2):

*"What buildRegBody does? Can you post the code?"* Sergio, this is a small method that builds the body of the email from a template.

Loteq, thank you for your suggestion. I do have all the files encoded correctly plus Tomcat was set to encode files as UTF-8. 
Problem was with JAVA running Tomcat. Solved by adding:

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

to the 'JAVA OPTS' of Catalina.sh or the /etc/init.d/Tomcat script (depending on your environment) as well as setting encoding statements in connector elements in Tomcat server xml (see above).
I hope that saves someone else the headache it caused me!

Comment: Just FYI; the users you are referencing here aren't being notified that you are replying to them.